# Remove square brackets at beginning and ending of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove square brackets from beginning and end of a string, if they are existing.

```
[Just a string]
Just a string
Just a string [comment]
[Just a string [comment]]
```

Should result in

```
Just a string
Just a string
Just a string [comment]
Just a string [comment]
```

I tried to build an regex, but I don't get it in a correct way, as it doesn't look for the position:

```
string.replace(/[\[\]]+/g,'')
```

Comment: What about `[Just a string [comment]`?

Comment: Use the `^` and `$` anchors

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is invalid, but would result in `Just a string [comment`

Comment: So you could probably also use `string.replace(/^\[|]$/g, '')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string.replace(/^\[(.+)\]$/,'$1')
```

should do the trick.

- `^` matches the begining of the string
- `$` matches the end of the string.
- `(.+)` matches everything in between, to report it back in the final string.

Comment: `console.log("[just a [string]".replace(/^\[(.+)\]$/,'$1'));` will return `"just a [string"`

Comment: OP doesn't want to build a bracket matcher, just a regex that removes final and first bracket, if both are present. Please don't over-assume.

Comment: You're assuming _"OP doesn't want to build a bracket matcher"_. We're both making assumptions, and I'm just pointing out a potential flaw.

Comment: @Cerbrus we only have what the OP gives us in way of definition for the problem. And in the comments on the question they have already stated that that input would have been invalid anyway.

Comment: Aren't reliable pieces of software supposed to be capable of dealing with invalid input? In other words: Shouldn't it check for invalid input?

Comment: @blue112 You are right, I just need that simple thing.

Comment: Anyway, this won't match `"[word\nline]"` because `.` does not match *everything*.

Comment: @Cerbrus: yes, but those are two separate problems. Checking the validity and removing the outer brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Blue112 provided a solution to remove `[` and `]` from the beginning/end of a *line* (if both are present).

To remove `[` and `]` from start/end of a **string** (if both are present) you need

```
input.replace(/^\[([\s\S]*)]$/,'$1')
```

or

```
input.replace(/^\[([^]*)]$/,'$1')
```

In JS, to match any symbol including a newline, you either use `[\s\S]` (or `[\w\W]` or `[\d\D]`), or `[^]` that matches any *non-nothing*.

```js
var s = "[word  \n[line]]";
console.log(s.replace(/^\[([\s\S]*)]$/, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better reg exp to do it, but a basic one would be:

```js
var strs = [
  "[Just a string]",
  "Just a string",
  "Just a string [comment]",
  "[Just a string [comment]]"
];

var re = /^\[(.+)\]$/;
strs.forEach( function (str) {
  var updated = str.replace(re,"$1");
  console.log(updated);
});
```

[Reg Exp Visualizer](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5C%5B(.%2B)%5C%5D%24%2F)

Comment: It is identical to blue112's solution.

Comment: That is what happens when you go get coffee and than answer